# Applying a style to ListBoxItem without affecting ComboboxItem inside

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` using a `DataTemplate`. The single `ListBoxItems` are displayed as a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox`. I now want to use a Style for the `ListBoxItems` without using it for the items of the inner `ComboBoxes`. Unfortunately, `ComboBoxItem` inherits from `ListBoxItem` which seems make this impossible. Or am I missing something here?

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="comboBoxI" Margin="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="320" Padding="1,1,1,1" 
                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeOtherCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationInfo}" Width="Auto" Padding="1,1,1,1">
                                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I also tried adding another style for `ComboBoxItem`, but in this case I don't know how to reset the colors to default.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Hendrik.

Comment: If you only want to show a list but don't need selection abilities you could use an ItemsControl instead of your ListBox.

Comment: That's a good hint indeed as I actually tried to hide the selection abilities by settings the style! :)

I wrapped the ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer and it seems to work nicely. I'm still interested in a solution using ListBox/ComboBox/Styles, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are better solutions. But as you mentioned you could restore the default colors:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextColor}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

**Remark**

Unfortunately applying the `ListBoxItem` style to this `ListBox` only in `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` will not work because you change system brushes valid for all inner controls and not `ListBoxItem` properties.